# RetroFit status code 201 interpreted as error

Tags: retrofit

I am developing a RESTful API, which has an endpoint, that creates an entity. This endpoint is called with POST and responds with 201, and a field in the body.

I see that Retrofit, interprets this 201 response as failure and calls the failure() method. One solution would be to change the response code to 200, but does anyone know why is it doing that?

Thanks

Comment: It is very strange what you say because in RestAdapter you  can find this condition `if (statusCode >= 200 && statusCode < 300) { `, this says which code is error 201 is not error for retrofit.

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation of the Callback class](http://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/retrofit/Callback.html), we have:

> **failure**(RetrofitError error)
>
> Unsuccessful HTTP response due to network
> failure, non-2XX status code, or unexpected exception.

That is, your 201 code status should be handled as success.

But there are some another causes for the issue you are facing. From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23107579/retrofit-invokes-failure-method-even-when-the-headers-status-code-is-200), you can see that retrofit can throws an exception that calls the failure method. Try see your gson parser, that is the POJO class that represents the expected response for this service.