# 201 created status code sent by django rest framework interpreted as failiure by jquery $.ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, django-rest-framework

I am simply using `django-rest-framework`s `CreateAPIView` which returns a response containing a 201 status code.

I would expect this to work with the standard javascript/jquery ajax functions. But apparently it does not.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29222961/retrofit-status-code-201-interpreted-as-error) is a similar issue where Retrofit throws an error. Any Ideas on how to debug this on jquery?

Comment: Could be a parsing error. Use arguments of error handler to get specifics. Show relevant code. Also is this a cross origin request?

Comment: the standart drf `CreateAPIView`  return `Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)`

Comment: please post your `jquery` code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you are returning an empty string as a response from your Django view and in your `ajax` code you set `dataType` as `json`.

The problem is that empty string is an error for json.

That's why try to set `dataType` to `text` or just don't set it at all. Remove it from your code.

Hope it helps!