# Android Retrofit + Rxjava: How to get response on non200 code?

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java2, okhttp

This is how my request looks like:

```
ApiService apiService = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);
Observable<Response<UserUpdateResponse>> response = apiService.updateUser(Utils.getHeader(), object);

response.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(this::onSuccessUpdate,
                    this::onErr,
                    this::hideDialogLoading);
```

It's supposed to return `'code':'205' 'msg':'successfully update'`. But when server response any code 201,202 (anything not 200) it will go to error. 

Here is the Error.

> java.net.ProtocolException: HTTP 205 had non-zero Content-Length: 121

So how do I prevent it from error, or how do I get error body? Thank you!.

Comment: Are you sure there is no other error? Try `retrofitError.getCause()`.
Check if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23107579/retrofit-invokes-failure-method-even-when-the-headers-status-code-is-200

Comment: Hi @Yousefkhan , I'm using Retrofit2, do I need to create RetrofitError class?

Comment: look at https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1218. Quoting jake's comment "There are three ways to construct your observable: Observable<BodyType>, Observable<Response<BodyType>>, or Observable<Result<BodyType>>. For the first version, there's nowhere to hang non-200 response information so it is included in the exception passed to onError. For the latter two, the data is encapsulated in the Response object and can be accessed by calling errorBody()."

Comment: I got this error

     io.reactivex.exceptions.CompositeException: 2 exceptions occurred. 
        at io.reactivex.internal.observers.LambdaObserver.onError(LambdaObserver.java:80)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.checkTerminated(ObservableObserveOn.java:276)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.drainNormal(ObservableObserveOn.java:172)
        at 
...

Comment: add the above to your question itself

Comment: the error states ProtocolException which has no response object. I doesn't make sense if I use HttpException to get errorBody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So technically, I can get response 2xx. The problem was that server response body in response code 205 that suppose to be null (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.6). So after set body null on server, android side works fine.

Answer (score 2):

HTTP response codes have a predefined definition and some have requirements that they must fullfill to be considered a valid HTTP payload. You cannot redefine what these codes mean for your application and expect well-implemented clients to accept it.

Looking specifically at [HTTP 205 - Reset Content](https://httpstatuses.com/205), which has the following requirement:

> Since the 205 status code implies that no additional content will be provided, a server MUST NOT generate a payload in a 205 response.

Generally applications will just return HTTP 200 for all requests and include application-specific error codes in the payload. What you're doing does not make much sense.

Comment: Hi @Kiskae, thank for response. But since the document say, https://httpstatuses.com/ 2xx is success why can't serve response it?

Comment: 2xx simply means the request did what it needed to do, not that it sent back a full response.